# iOS 10 UIWebView not opening links on web page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, wkwebview, sfsafariviewcontroller

I'm displaying a web page in a UIWebView inside an app. There are links in the UIWebView which are no longer clickable as of iOS 10. Some elements of the page I can interact with, but others I cannot so I don't know if its a java script issue or what (I'm not the programmer of the web page, just the app)

I do not have this issue with earlier versions of iOS (9 and less)

I have tried UIWebView, and WKWebView. It does work in SafariViewController but this doesn't give me the flexibility that I want

Using Objective C

Tried targeting iOS 8, 9, 10 ~ same issue

*Also if I goto the page in regular Safari Browser it does work, so it seems like some kind of issue with UIWebView

Comment: Can you supply the url for test? And which links are not working?

Comment: @MobileMon did you manage to fix this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: How did you get rid of this issue? I know how but it doesn't meet my requirement that you need to upgrade to higher IOS (ios 12 works for me). I wanna get it work in my jailbreak environment. Don't know how.